zip -FF on split files quietly
I have a bunch of split zip files which is large size.
Trying to -FF on the split files.
During the process zip asks questions like "zip file.z002 not found" and asks to select different options. These options are non standard options and are not part of the standard argument list of zip. So I don't see a way to pass these as args.
How can I do -FF quietly on split files?
